# How to use column from other table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

On my navigation bar, I want to put the user's **name** and **avatar**. Everytime the users login into their account, they can see their own name and avatar on the navbar. Before this, the **name** and **avatar** column is in my **user table**. Now, I move them to other table for each type of user such as buyers, contractors and admins. Both table are related by using **user_id** column.

**users table**

```
id
role
email
password
```

**buyers table**

```
id
user_id
name
avatar
email
```

**contractors table**

```
id
user_id
name
avatar
email
```

**navbar.blade**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/{{auth()->user()->avatar}}"class="img-circle" alt="Avatar <span>{{auth()->user()->name}}</span><i class="icon-submenu lnr lnr-chevron-down"></i></a>
```

I should not use `{{auth()->user()->avatar}}` and `{{auth()->user()->name}}` because there is no `name` and `avatar` column in **user table** anymore. So, what query I need to use?

Comment: Do you have a Buyer and Contractor properly connected to the User model? It looks like a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: Nope, I don’t have. Do I need to use that way?

Comment: It will make things much easier for you. But make sure you need to separate these two types by a table. If they share all columns, maybe a simple type flag would be enough? That would make the fetching easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using polymorphic relationships. More about this here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

If the information inside your "type" tables are the same across the board, you will be better of just adding one column called `type` inside your `users` table. This column can be an `enum`.

If you want to maintain your current approach, polymorphic relationships for the rescue!

You should remove the `user_id` from your `buyers`, `contractors`, and `admins` tables. Instead, you will have two polymorphic columns in your `users` table.

Your tables should look like:

**users table**

```
id
role
email
password
typable_id - integer
typable_type - string
```

**buyers table**

```
id
name
avatar
email
```

**contractors table**

```
id
name
avatar
email
```

**admins table**

```
id
name
avatar
email
```

Your models should look like:

**User model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function typable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**Buyer model**

```
class Buyer extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'typable');
    }
}
```

**Contractor model**

```
class Contractor extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'typable');
    }
}
```

**Admin model**

```
class Admin extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'typable');
    }
}
```

Your view should look like:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/{{auth()->user()->typable->avatar}}">
    <span>{{auth()->user()->typable->name}}</span>
</a>
```

You can add as many types as you want, just add another table and model. Your `User` model is now typable.

---

**Updated:**

When you need to create a new user, create first the `typable`, after that, create the user with the relationship function:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $buyer = Buyer::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'avatar' => $request->avatar,
        'email' => $request->email,
    ]);

    $buyer->user()->create([
        'role' => 'buyer',
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt('system'),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I just put some dummy data, you can put there whatever you want. Updated again to look right.

Comment: If this question was resolved, please mark it as so. For this other problem, please do open another question and explain everything rich in detail. Tomorrow I take a look, now its bedtime. Going to sleep...